# Find all the non-isomorphic Abelian groups of order $1600$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

So the twelve Abelian groups of order $1600$ are:

1. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_{64}$
2. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_{32} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} $
3. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times
       \mathbb{Z}_2$
4. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
5. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
6. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$
7. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times
       \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
8. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times
       \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
9. $\mathbb{Z}_{25}  \times \mathbb{Z}_{8} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
10. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_4 $
11. $\mathbb{Z}_{25} \times \mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times
       \mathbb{Z}_2$
12. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{64}$
13. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{32} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} $
14. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times
        \mathbb{Z}_2$
15. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
16. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
17. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$
18. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times
        \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
19. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times
        \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
20. $\mathbb{Z}_{5}  \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{8} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$
21. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_4 $
22. $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times
       \mathbb{Z}_2$

Is this correct?

Comment: What about $25 \times 8 \times 8$, for example?

Comment: @KajHansen Then, how many groups should I have? Isnt't it just $ 2 \times 6 = 12?$

Comment: The isomorphism classes for finite abelian groups are of the form $\displaystyle \bigoplus_k \mathbb{Z}_{q_k}$, where the $q_k$'s are powers of primes (*not necessarily distinct*).  In this scenario, for example, $5^2, 2^2, 2^2, 2^2$ would correspond to a distinct and valid group, as would $5^2, 2^2, 2^4$, as would $5, 5, 2^3, 2^3$ and so forth (all not listed).  The only thing that would not count as distinct is a mere re-ordering of the $q_k$'s.

Comment: Edited answer Thanks

Comment: Number 3. and 11. are identical, as are 4. and 9., 14. and 22., and 15. and 20. You've forgotten the two forms $64=4^3=4^2\cdot2^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1600=5^2.2^6$, number of non isomorphic abelian groups $=P(2).P(6)=2.11=22$ where $P$ is the partition function. Noting them all down is too tedious.
We have for an abelian group of order $p^n$ the number of non-isomorphic classes is $P(n)$ since a typical such group has the structure $\bigoplus_{i=1} ^k Z/p^{\alpha_i}Z$ where $\sum_{i=1} ^k\alpha_i=n$ and distinct partitions of $n$ give rise to different non isomorphic groups

Comment: How is it that i calculate the number of non isomorphic abelian groups?

Comment: @JohnPerks You need the [partition function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function)

Comment: Edited answer Thanks